# Encryption not working in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I wish to encrypt the contents of my program when the program is visited in Windows Explorer but I find that none of the files are encrypted once the program is installed. I have set encryption to yes and set a password but none of the files in any of the folders are encrypted. Besides setting encryption and setting a password, I'm not sure what else one can do to ensure encryption. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the Inno Setup encryption encrypts only the installer. The installed files are decrypted during installation. That's by design. How would your application be able to use them, if they were encrypted using a password the application is not aware of?

If you want to have the installed files encrypted, you have to encrypt them yourself before compiling the installer. And your application must prompt user for a password to be able to decrypt them.

You can also of course hard-code the password to your application. But that's not safe enough. There's generally no way to safely encrypt data in a way that allows automatic decryption.